# Can't Do Numeric Operations with decimal types in C# (Log10, Abs)

Tags: c#, .net, math

I want to be able to do `Log10` and `Abs` operations on `decimal` type (128-bit) in C# and don't want to cast to a `double` (64-bit) and lose precision.

Since the standard `System.Math` methods only accept `double` how can I achieve this?

Example:

```
decimal x = 100M;
decimal LogResult = Math.Log10(x);    // only works with doubles
decimal AbsResult = Math.Abs(x);      // only works with doubles
```

Comment: [DecimalMath.DecimalEx](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DecimalMath.DecimalEx/)

Comment: FYI, `Math.Abs()` supports decimals.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do simple math operations like division, you should use `System.Decimal`.

> ### From MSDN:
>
> The decimal keyword denotes a 128-bit data type. Compared
> to floating-point types, the decimal type has a greater precision and a
> smaller range, which makes it suitable for financial and monetary
> calculations.

`System.Math` only takes Doubles for several key pieces of functionality. Sadly, you are working with high precision numbers, and since Decimal is 128 bit and Double is only 64, the conversion results in a loss of precision.

Apparently there are some possible plans to make most of `System.Math` handle Decimal.

Mathdotnet, A mathematical open source (MIT/X11, LGPL & GPL) library written in C#/.Net, aiming to provide a self contained clean framework for symbolic algebraic and numerical / scientific computations.

Extreme Optimization Mathematics Library for .NET (paid)

I've used it before and it's my recommendation.
DecimalMath A relative newcomer, this one advertises itself as: Portable math support for Decimal that Microsoft forgot and more.